# App submission folder/archive size exceeding 200mb for simple game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Im not sure if this is the right stackExchange community to ask this question but I cant find any other more suitable. So if youre willing to help here it is:

Ive created a very simple game, much like the game PianoTiles. My folder size is upwards of 200mb because I included 3 Ad Networks (adMob and mediations), and their SDK's are around 50mb each. More importantly, I DO need to include these SDK's in my first build right?) Will this be the final size of my app after submission? 200mb is too much for a simple game like mine. Should I just use one adNetwork?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right place to ask your question. First, the number that is most important isn't the size of your project's folder, but the the estimated size that iTunes Connect predicts your app will take to install on devices. You discover that by archiving and uploading to iTunes Connect, and then select your app, find the estimated file size by clicking on App Store File Size under Activity -> All Builds -> Select Build -> press App Store File Size.

As to the number of ad networks, that is up to you, but increasing the number will permanently increase your binary size.

See Screenshot:[image]

Comment: From your screenshot it looks like im missing the link to "App store file size" It only shows the compressed file size

Comment: You could make a TestFlight build - that's how my estimates were generated. But as you can see, the sizes are a fraction of the compressed size (which is smaller than the archive itself).